# Can post permalinks be index-based in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to navigate to `/posts/10` and have Wordpress take me to the correct post if ordered by date?

What's a good place to start? I've checked the [wp-routes](https://github.com/lucatume/wp-routes) library, but no idea how to integrate it with non-JSON requests, and examples are fairly limited.

This is for a webcomics site, which usually have pages indexed, instead of named. i.e `http://example.com/comic/20`

If anyone has done something like this before, any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just change your permalinks to get the behavior you want?

Comment: @Difster Not quite. If I add a comic page in the middle or one changes order, I'd have to rename all post slugs.

Comment: I see what you're getting at. It is a difficult problem. I'm not sure there is any good solution that would not be really hard to maintain.